# Chopin piano piece title "doubtful"?

Tags: chopin

I was listening to Pandora, and a piano piece by Chopin came on titled

> Nocturne for piano in C sharp minor (doubtful), KK Anh.IA/6

And I simply am wondering why is the key doubtful? Is that what's "doubtful" about the piece or am I missing something? I would think Chopin knows what key he's writing in, no?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work appears in the Chomiński's catalogue of Chopin.  It is the authorship that is doubtful.  Often such works are called spurious rather than doubtful.

The score is [here](https://imslp.org/wiki/Nocturne_oubli%C3%A9e_(Chopin%2C_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)).